# image not sharing in ios whatsapp using react-native-share?

Tags: ios, react-native, share

I am using react-native-share to share contents and links and images.
Here I can share the all of these in all the app in android and ios except the Whatsapp in ios.

I've added the native dependencies as per the instructions in `react-native-share`. I've added all of these

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
  <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```

How to get this done in ios whatsapp ?

```
_downloadImageAndShare(url ,title, message) {

RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache: true })
  .fetch('GET', url)
  .then(resp => resp.readFile('base64')
      .then(base64 => ({ resp, base64 })))
  .then(obj => {
    const headers = obj.resp.respInfo.headers;
    const type = headers['Content-Type'];
    const dataUrl = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + obj.base64;
    return { url: dataUrl, title, message };

  })
  .then(options => Share.open(options)).catch(err => {err && 
 console.log(err); })         
 }
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question, can you provide the snippet that you are using to share the image for whatsapp?

Comment: i will re-edit the question

Comment: @khalifathul: Have you found any solution for that? I am facing same issue specially for iOS.